# Android: Change actionbar icon after click and change it back after onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I try to change the icon of the action bar to a progress bar in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` method.

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case R.id.progressitem2:
        mProgress = item;
        mProgressCreate = mProgress;
        mProgress.setActionView(R.layout.progress);
        mLayout.removeView(mTable);
        // Execute code that change mTable again.
        return true;
    }
```

progress.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:paddingLeft="4dp"
              android:paddingRight="4dp"
              android:gravity="center" >
    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The action bar is created in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
    mProgress = menu.getItem(0);
    mProgressCreate = mProgress;
    return true;
}
```

action_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/progressitem2" 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
            android:title="Reload"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:visible="true" />
</menu>
```

This works good. The progress icon is shown after I click the action bar icon.

I try to keep the reference of the original action bar symbol in `mProgressCreate` and try to add the action view back at the end of the `onCreate()` method:

```
mProgress.setActionView(mProgressCreate.getActionView());
```

But this do not work...

What`s wrong here?

Regards,
Sandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I simply forgot to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` before I reset the action view with `mProgress.setActionView(mProgressCreate.getActionView());`

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
mProgress.setActionView(mProgressCreate.getActionView());
```

And everything is working fine :-).