# Android ActionBar - Item icon change continuously?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, icons

On my ActionBar there is one item that has an icon about a star(without filled).
When the user clicks on it, the icon changes to another icon(filled star).
But the problem is that if the user cliccks again the icon doesn't change one more time.

So, this is what i want

icon1->click->icon2->click->icon1->click->icon2

My item xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/bookmark"
    android:icon="@drawable/bookmark"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Add to Favorites"/>
```

My Java for actionBar:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_desc, menu);
}



@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.bookmark){



        // i tried this: something like: if(item.getIcon() == (R.drawable.nobookmark){} it doesn't work 


        item.setIcon(R.drawable.nobookmark);

        return true;
    }

    return true;

  }
```

Comment: This is true whether you are using ActionBarSherlock or not.

Comment: please explain in more details, and in code examples

Comment: but i don't want to use an externam library, i know it can be done just i don't know the logarith and the logic for that, so please help

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501943/android-change-actionbar-icon-after-click-and-change-it-back-after-oncreate?rq=1

Comment: if you can change my code accoring to your answer in a spereate box(so i can accept your answer) then i will accept your answer very happily, i will put a green check mark for your answer, pleaseeeeee

Comment: why did you say that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `item.xml` make it checkable:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/bookmark"
    android:icon="@drawable/nobookmark"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Add to Favorites"/>
```

In the java you must manually toggle the checked state and select the icon:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  if(item.getItemId() == R.id.bookmark){
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    item.setIcon(item.isChecked() ? R.drawable.bookmark : R.drawable.nobookmark);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: in my java or on my actionbar <item> xml file? please update your answer and i will accept your answer.

Comment: but now it only shows the drawable icon from  android:state_checked="true"

it doens't change if i click on the icon on the action bar.

Comment: android:state_checked="false" is not working
should i change or delete anything in my java file?

Comment: if i click on the icon, nothing happens,

Comment: adn where should i write this setChecked code?
please put this code in my code i wrote in my question, then i will accept your answer

Comment: I'm going to test it out before I do. In mean time take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652368/using-a-selector-for-a-menuitem-in-the-actionbar

Comment: Scrap the selector, it doesn't work for menu item icons.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: YOU ARE A BLODDY GENIUS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I HAVE BEEN TRYING TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM FOR 4 HOURS!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I LOVE YOU, YOU ARE THE GOD OF PRGOAMMING, YOU ARE THE BEST PROGRAMMER IN THE WORLD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!